# Ubuntu 12.04 server copy authorized_keys to different server

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I have setup key auth on a ubuntu 12.04 server. Is it possible to just copy the content of authorized_keys to another ubuntu 12.04 box that this gets all auth keys as well? This would safe time to not add each user keyfile again.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. It will copy all the trusted keys. Make sure permission of the file is right and it is in the right location.